# Grails how to change the current locale

Tags: grails, internationalization, locale

How can I change the current locale ?

- I tried to put `controller/action?lang=de` but my locale is still `en_US`
- I tried to override the value using this piece of code:

  ```
  def key = "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER"
  def localeResolver = request.getAttribute(key)
  localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("de","DE"))
  ```

Nothing changed.

- I tried to override the value using this piece of code:

  ```
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU;
  RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, new Locale("de","DE"))
  ```

And... nothing happened. i still got my locale set to `en_US`.

Any idea to change the locale ?

Answer (score 28):

According to the chapter [10. Internationalization](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/single.html#10.%20Internationalization) of the Grails documentation, Grails supports i18n out of the box and you should indeed be able to change the locale using the `lang` parameter:

> By default the user locale is detected
>   from the incoming `Accept-Language`
>   header. However, you can provide users
>   the capability to switch locales by
>   simply passing a parameter called `lang`
>   to Grails as a request parameter:
>
> ```
> /book/list?lang=de
> ```
>
> Grails will automatically switch the
>   user locale and store it in a cookie
>   so subsequent requests will have the
>   new header.

But sometimes you may want to preset the default language because not all your applications will be in english. To do this, all you have to do is to set your `localeResolver` in your `resources.groovy` spring configuration file as shown below:

```
beans = {
   localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
      defaultLocale = new Locale("de","DE")
      java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
   }
}
```

Now, without more details, I can't say why using the `lang` parameter isn't working in your case. Just in case, how do you know that the locale is still en_US?.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution to change the defaultLocale but I still get an en_US locale. Good question to retrieve my current locale I use 'request.locale'. I can also see that grails is still reading the default bundle message and not the 'de' version. Thanks for any clues!

Comment: Just wanted to be sure your validation process was ok and it is :) 
But I must say that this is really weird. Can you say if the `Accept-Language` header is set? What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Yes weird is definitely the word... I'm using Grails 1.1. I've just check the header of the http request and I can see : 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'

Comment: That's not the expected behavior. However, I couldn't find anything close to your problem in Grails's Jira. This can't be missed though if it's a bug. I don't get it.

Comment: Tested this in `2.4.3` and this is working to set the starting locale. I needed this to set NL as default language.

Comment: I've used jawr-plugin to translate text in javascript. I found out that defaultLocale = new Locale('fi', 'FI') is just enough to set default language to app and Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale) actually prevented jawr to change the language.

Answer (score 6):

Do you try to change locale in application root url (eg. `http://localhost:8080/myapp/?lang=de`)?

In Grails basic setup trying to change locale in application root url does not work. Grails change locale in `localChangeInterceptor` which is called before all controllers are called. When you access application root url, no controller is called as can be seen in default UrlMappings.

That's why changing locale in application root url does not work. If you try to change url in some controller, it works.

Current locale is stored under key `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` in http session. You can check it there.

Correct solution is to map root url to some controller in UrlMappings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But yes I was trying to change the locale on one of my controller and it didn't work. That was really weird because the documentation was describing the same behavior as what you are telling but my locale wasn’t changing… so I build my own internationalization feature using a session variable to store the current locale.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand the way you are checking the locale "request.locale" is wrong, it gives the locale of browser, not the locale of grails applciation.

You should use "**LocaleContextHolder.locale**".

In **2.0.3** it changes the locale by simply passing parameter `lang=someLocale`.

Answer (score 5):

This is problably way too late but for reference, I do this in my index page controller:

```
session['org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'] = new Locale("es", "PR")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and it was because a space. I had:

`[space]messages_de.properties` instead `messages_de.properties`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this awhile back when proxy-ing through an older version of Apache2.2 and using the grails (2.3.9) war file.   I've had better luck using  mod_proxy_html (3.1) / Apache 2.4.     Maybe more advanced versions of grails fix this.