# Is there a way to set the timezone to UTC within the DataSource config

Tags: database, grails, groovy, timezone, datasource

We have a Grails 2.1.0 project and our staging and production dbs are on shared db servers.

We would like to set the timezone to UTC (0) on a per connection basis, is there an easy way to do this from the DataSource.groovy file.

Other suggestions also welcome.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605953/how-to-change-mysql-timezone-in-java-connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jared's answer to [grails/mysql timezone change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390770/grails-mysql-timezone-change)  suggests that we don't need to adjust the mysql timezone at all, as the datetime fields are stored as MySql DateTime. I solved this for my local machine by adding -Duser.timezone=UTC to $JAVA_OPTS, so this may be the required solution.

We've tried this across local and stage environments and this does solve the issue.