# built-in language change doesn't work at Grails2

Tags: grails, internationalization

I have Grails 2 application where I've already added i18n/messages_ru.properties. So, according to documentation I use request ?lang=ru (f.e. userOperations/index?lang=es) but nothing changed. Languages is still default, lang cookies wasn't created.
What's wrong? How can I fix it up?

PS. I use Oracle Java7 on Ubuntu

Comment: Maybe this topic helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569446/grails-how-to-change-the-current-locale

Comment: I saw this post, add answer "According to the chapter 10. Internationalization of the Grails documentation, Grails supports i18n out of the box and you should indeed be able to change the locale using the lang parameter" isn't work as I wrote

Comment: And what about the default messages that the `messages_ru.properties` already has? Does grails fail to show those too ?

Comment: I special created new application with only auto-generated code. And tried change language with ?lang=ru. Also, I tried to change my language: es, fr and so on. Nothing works. I really disappointed

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to change?  If you look at the default index page (the one that lists controllers, etc) it doesn't use messages - it's all hard-coded.

I just tested and it works for me in 2.0.3.  Here is what I did:

1. Create new Application
2. Create domain class with single field (String name)
3. Run "Generate All" for that class
4. The gsp's created will have something like this:

   ```
    <g:message code="yourDomainClass.name.label" default="Name" />
   ```

Now if I don't do anything and look at the page, even with lang=ru or lang=es it is STILL going to say Name.  But then I went in and added to the messages_es.properties file the following:

```
    yourDomainClass.name.label=Nombre
```

and when I refreshed the page it says "Nombre" instead of "Name."

There are defaults in the message files for certain messages like "default.home.label" and when I used the lang=es those did change to Spanish like they should without me doing anything.

Comment: I my new app I added <g:message code="default.paginate.prev" /> to index.gsp page to test i18n. And it doesn't work!

In my own application I:
1) Create new app
2) create my own gps With g:message code="mycode"
3) in i18n files put mycode="something"
Doesn't work

Comment: I use Ubuntu and java 7 u4 - maybe that is problem

Comment: Do you still have the standard 'messages.properties' file in the i18n directory? If not copy one from another project and try it again.  I found one other hit out there where someone had this problem when they had removed that file and ONLY had the language specific ones in there.

Comment: yes, I have messages.properties file as file for default language

Comment: Wow - this is a strange one.  I'm guessing at this point but one other thing I've read is that i18n relies on going through a controller - that is why the default index.gsp doesn't work with it.  In your case there is a "UserOperations" controller right?  It's not just a directory with an index.gsp correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you configured url(or it was default "/"(view:"index")) mapping to render view directly without a controller. Create a controller and render a view in it. Without a controller it doesn't work!