# Displaying text in differnt locales on one page

Tags: grails, internationalization

I need to display sentences in my GSP in differnt locales.

The following documentation states that g:message takes a locale param.

I can't find an example of this anywhere. Has anyone done this?

```
<p><g:message code="welcome.into.text1" locale="sv_SE"/></p>
<p><g:message code="welcome.into.text1" locale="en_US"/></p>
```

Obviosuly, I have messages_sv.properties &  messages_en_US.properties.

Thanks

Comment: Did this not returned as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify locale explicitely use Locale object instead of String, e.g.:

```
<g:message code="welcome.into.text1" locale="${Locale.US}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html

[Grails how to change the current locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569446/grails-how-to-change-the-current-locale)