# Grails: How to get locale in a GSP page that sits outsides of controller / domain / service?

Tags: grails, internationalization, gsp

I have an internazionalised application with language selection, based on Grails and the kickstarter plugin. As per the configuration in its UrlMappings, there are some pages without controller. On these, only the default locale is applied no matter what a user has actually selected. Further, on them changing the language does not work. g:message tags output with the default locale; I tried

```
<g:set var="locale"
   value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE' ?: org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}"/>
```

(forgot where I found that) .. but following that nothing changes.

Comment: When you say "there are some pages without controller", are you saying that multiple controllers will render this page?  Or are you saying the page is an orphan and not triggered by a controller?  if it's the former, you can just throw the local into the gsp map on all the actions that render (or could potentially render through a `g:if` tag), otherwise just stick it in the session when the user logs in if you use it frequently.  If it's the latter, then I don't understand how that would work.

Comment: @TedDelezene It is as you said: "the page is an orphan and not triggered by a controller". For a short guide on how to render a gsp page outsides of controller or anything, see the comment by Graeme-Rocher at: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Rendering-a-GSP-without-controller-request-td1390514.html "You can access a gsp directly by placing it in the web-app directory and using the .gsp extension, or you can add a url mapping that maps straight to a GSP: `"/foo"(view:"mypage.gsp") `" - that would go in the UrlMappings.grooy and all requests to /foo would then simply show that page.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is [a bug in grails versions prior to 2.4.4](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9465)

I worked around it by retrieving the locale at the top of the gsp in question like so:

```
 <g:set var="lang" value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'}"/>
```

(from [this blog post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/finding-users-locale-in-gsp/)) and then adding the locale to the messages I want to appear translated in the page, using [a solution by @
SergeiShushkevich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14385592/2067690) like so:

```
<g:message code="text.label" locale="${lang}"/>
${message([code:'text.label', locale:lang])}
```