# Grails: How to get i18 message using the current localization?

Tags: grails, localization, internationalization

I'm coding in Grails (2.2.4) + groovy application, and I need to get i18 message, what are the possible ways to return this kind of value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine when I used:

```
def getMessage( String code, Object[] args = null)
{
    // assuming the test cwd is the project dir (where application.properties is)
    URL url = new File('grails-app/i18n').toURI().toURL()
    def messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource()
    messageSource.bundleClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(url)
    messageSource.basename = 'messages'
    messageSource.getMessage(code, args, Locale.ENGLISH)
}
```

And in the setup function I mocked my functions like this (which using this function above):

```
    ResponsHelper.metaClass.static.jsonError = { String code, Object[] args = null ->
        getMessage(code, args)
    }

    ResponsHelper.metaClass.static.jsonErrorsNoArgsInList = { List errors ->
        errors.collect {
            getMessage(it, [])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the official documentation - http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/i18n.html You can find there all interesting information about how to set and read i18n messages.

In essence:

Put your i18n messages in grails-app/i18n/messages_[lang_code].properties where [lang_code] represents language code you are interested in. This file is simple ini-like file, so it contains key=values e.g.

```
site_title=Your site internationalized site name
```

Then you can use this message. If you would like to display it in your gsp view, use simple taglig:

```
<g:message code="site_title" />
```

As you can see, "code" attributes is associated with the key of your message in the properties file. If you would like to get your i18n message in the controller, then you will have to inject "messageSource" bean:

```
def messageSource
```

And after that you can receive your message in the controller action by using this method:

```
messageSource.getMessage('site_title', null, request.locale, 'here you can put some default value if i18n label is not found')
```

It will return the message associated with 'site_title' key.

One more thing - Grails app uses your browser locale. If you would like to change them, pass the lang parameter in your url request e.g. http://yourappdomain.com?lang=en

Comment: I saw this link earlier, it's not helping me so much. I need to find some good practices about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean how to change them at runtime ?

Mainly you use `<g:message code="this.is.your.code.localization.hellolable"/>`

Like on spring / resource.groovy file. and controller way of passing ?

[Look this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569446/grails-how-to-change-the-current-locale)

There are two class involved in messaging 
1.`message bean itself` 
2.`PluginAwareMessage` ... of some sort .. make sure u have those injected or available. You could use even this services to access message using code.

Comment: Actually, my problem is get some message when running Spock unit test, it seems like the file isn't readable or something like that, I always keep on getting *'org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'default.access.denied.message' for locale 'en_US'.'*, either to this locale or any other one which surely have this message inside it.

Comment: I need to call this function when i'm in groovy class, and not in GSP file

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you going to use g.message tag inside src:

```
def grailsApplication = ApplicationHolder.application
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib')
g.message(code:'your.code.in.message.property', locale:'locale.name') // set locale only for this message
```

Or you can use this for application level:

```
def localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request); // returns a SessionLocaleResolver
def locale = new Locale("fr", "CA");
localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
```

Comment: first option throws exception - *org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib' is defined*.

For the second one, I can't get request object, maybe there is a code for that?